# Javascript Problems in Firefox but not in IE Debugging problems VIsual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, html

Help I'm very new with web developing using ASP.NET. Why is the my web app does not give the desired output like IE does when debugging my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    h1{color:Blue}
    h2{color:Red}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowColor() {
        alert("You selected " + SelectColor.value);
        BodyContent.style.backgroundColor = SelectColor.value;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="BodyContent">
    <h1>HelloWorld</h1>
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <p>
    This is my first Web Page</p>
    <hr />
    Please select color:
    <select id="SelectColor">
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
        <option value="silver">silver</option>
    </select>
    <input id="ButtonColor" type="button" value="Select" onclick="ShowColor()" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that FF does not executes the javascript "ShowColor" when i clicked the Select button but IE does.

[image]

```
    function ShowColor() {
        alert("You selected " + SelectColor.value);
        BodyContent.style.backgroundColor = SelectColor.value;
    }
```

Comment: The question you are asking is not clear. First you mention the Firefox is the problem and then you mention that "Problem is that IE executes the javascript "ShowColor" when i clicked the Select button", problem being the key word in the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. im really sorry. What im trying to express is that Firefox cannot output it correctly like IE does.. because firefox does not execute the jscript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript function should be as follows:

```
function ShowColor() {
    alert("You selected " + document.getElementById("SelectColor").value);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("SelectColor").value;
}
```

You need to select the actual elements by using javascript. For example document.gelElementById("id of element"), and then change the documents color. This should work in any browser.

The function now shows the appropriate selected value and actually changes the background of the webpage.

Comment: Thank you very much @jacqijw. Correct me if im wrong. I just realize that the asp.net codes(shall i say VS web app codes) just work only  with IE. Thanks for helping me out. I can proceed now with tutorials.

Comment: @Jed - This is another reason why you should never look to IE as a reference for how things should work.

Comment: @jacqijw: can you help me with this: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629423/asp-net-mvc3-site-css/10629447#comment13777779_10629447)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selected;
function alertselected(selectobj) {
    selected = selectobj.selectedIndex;
}

function ShowColor() {
    alert("You selected " + selected);
    elm = document.getElementById("sample");
    document.getElementById("BodyContent").style.backgroundColor = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="BodyContent"><select id="sample" onChange="alertselected(this)">option>white</option><option>yellow</option><option>silver</option>
```

```
<input id="ButtonColor" type="button" value="Select" onclick="ShowColor()" /></div>
```