# ASP.NET MVC3 - Site.css

Tags: css, styles

Why is there no any change in my site.css when I change my code from:

```
.display-label, 
.editor-label 
{
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}
```

to

```
.display-label, 
.editor-label 
{   
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    color: Green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here my Details.cshtml :

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>

    <div class="display-label">LastName</div>
    <div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">FirstMidName</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">EnrollmentDate</div>
    <div class="display-field">
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.StudentID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Why is this happening? Is inheritance causing this?

Here's the whole Site.css :

```
body {
    background-color: #2E8B57;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
}

a:link {
    color: #034af3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: #505abc;
}

a:hover {
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    color: #12eb87;
}

p, ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

header,
footer,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
     font-size: 1em;
}

/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* you can specify a greater or lesser percentage for the 
page width. Or, you can specify an exact pixel width. */
.page {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header, #header {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
}

header h1, #header h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 32px !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #111;
}

#main 
{
clear: both;
    padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}

footer, 
#footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}



/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid {
display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

/* Styles for editor and display helpers
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.display-label, 
.editor-label 
{   
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    color: Green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.display-field, 
.editor-field 
{
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

.text-box {
    width: 30em;
}

.text-box.multi-line {
    height: 6.5em;
}

.tri-state {
    width: 6em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reason is some other style definition is overriding this one. Use `firebug` to see which styles are applied/ overridden.

If you want to override a purticular style, use the `important` keyword

```
.editor-label 
{   
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    color: Green !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Comment: I have these CSS errors. Do you think it is responsible why my style is not changed?

Validation (CSS 2.1): 'border-radius' is not a known CSS property name. 
Validation (CSS 2.1): 'border-radius' is not a known CSS property name. 
Validation (CSS 2.1): 'border-radius' is not a known CSS property name. 
Validation (CSS 2.1): 'text-shadow' is not a known CSS property

Comment: @Jed : Without overriding it works in the sample ( copied from the cSS you provided in the question)

Comment: Why it does not take effect immediately... What will i do? I know the codes are correct.

Comment: It just happened that it took effect when you suggested to put important but after few debug executions...

Comment: I just figured it out already... I need to reload the page or bypass the cache.. Hehehe... Certified noob